# Apollo GraphQL Client does not work on release build in react native

Tags: react-native, graphql, fetch-api, apollo

it's been around two weeks that I'm dealing with this problem.
at first, it did not work at all. After spending several days searching for a solution I could fix it by adding these lines of code to my index.js file.

```
XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ?
    GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest :
    GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;
    global.Blob = null
```

After that, it worked fine in the development mode and everything was fine.
But as soon as I released my app I realized it does not work in the release build!

I'm kind of sure it's a problem with fetch API that apollo uses behind the scenes. But I don't know what to do to fix it.

I also tried to run a new project and paste my code on it, but no luck.

this is my apollo client code:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import Statics from './statics'
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const customFetch = (uri, options) => {
  return fetch(uri, options)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 500) {  // or handle 400 errors
      return Promise.reject(response.status);
    }
    return response;
  });
};
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({uri:`${Statics.baseUrl}/graphql`, fetch:customFetch}) ,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isomorphic-fetch` instead of `fetch`